# Event trigging object method loses the object

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm not very used to javascript's prototyping syntax so this might be very simple.

```
function MyClass(){
   this.init = function(input){
      this.input.onkeyup = function(){
         this.change();
      }
   }
}
```

Obviously I've left some things out here, but this.input refers to an HTML `input` element. The problem here is that *this* in `this.change()` will no longer refer to the instance of MyClass but to the HTML-element. How can I get the object instead of the element?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Event handlers automatically point the `this` keyword to the element the event is firing on.  ECMA-262 5th Edition attempts to combat situations like this by implementing an old technique of "binding" a function to a specific object:

```
// From Prototype.js
if (!Function.prototype.bind) { // check if native implementation available
  Function.prototype.bind = function(){ 
    var fn = this, args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
        object = args.shift(); 
    return function(){ 
      return fn.apply(object, 
        args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
    }; 
  };
}
```

Usage:

```
function MyClass(){
   this.init = function(input){
      this.input.onkeyup = (function(){
         this.change();
      }).bind(this);
   }
}
```

The ECMAScript implementation is the same as the [PrototypeJS implementation](http://www.prototypejs.org/api/function/bind) (for which the code is above).

You could also implement it on a per-class basis:

```
function MyClass(){
   this.bind = function(){ 
       var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments),
           self = this,
           fn = args.shift();
       return function(){ 
         return fn.apply(self, 
           args.concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments))); 
       }; 
   };
   this.init = function(input){
      this.input.onkeyup = this.bind(function(){
         this.change();
      });
   }
}
```

The archaic ;-) option is to just store a reference to `this` outside of the function:

```
function MyClass(){
   var self = this;
   this.init = function(input){
      this.input.onkeyup = function(){
         self.change();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Should this be the preferred way instead of making use of a closure?

Comment: @Felix Kling: I certainly think so, especially if you're doing it a lot.  I added the closure solution anyway, to make the answer more complete.

Comment: Thanks! All good solutions. Think i'll go on the archaic version for now since it's only in one place i need it.